# Styling Issue in iPad Safari Browser, Setting Height Width Not working

Tags: css, html, safari, mobile-safari

I have set Height Width Margins Borders everything to ZERO , so as to get an hidden control (*dont wanted to use display:none*)

try the following on iPad safari and on any other safari/chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/bjfrud68/

```
<input type="date" name="57ffc08f-5f30-4b2d-8287-b65d12146cdc_DateOfBirth_touchpicker" style="height: 0px;width: 0px;border: 0px;padding: 0px;">
```

But When running on a MAC Safari , it works fine . i dont see the textbox
but when running on an iPad Safari ... it doesnt.. i can see the text box

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-webkit-appearance:none` to override IOS default styling

Comment: this makes the control disabled :( , not hidden

Comment: What this does is, remove the webkit applied styles.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the newest version of iPad's Safari browser and it is working fine. I guess you have to re-download the browser so that you will cover this issue. OR you can go with the suggestion of Mr. N.K as well, may be you will get a success.
[iPad app development](http://www.cygnismedia.com/mobile-phone-application/ipad-application.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the input is display: inline; - then you can't really set height for it... (I think...)  You'll need it to be block so that it can have dimensions. Also - this should be dealt with in a more robust manner - or may need overflow: hidden;

http://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/